# Graph of a parabola on pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have a graph of a parabola.  Why is there a "*10^{4}" typeset on it?!  How do I get "20,000" printed as a tick mark along the x-axis?  I tried `xticklabels={$20,000$}` and the code would not compile.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=3in, height=3in, axis lines=middle, clip=false,
    axis lines=middle, clip=false,
    xmin=-1000,xmax=37320.5,
    ymin=-200000,ymax=725000,
    restrict y to domain=-200000:725000,
    xtick={20000},ytick={\empty},
    ticklabel style={font=\scriptsize},
    xticklabels={$20000$},
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    axis line style={shorten >=-12.5pt, shorten <=-12.5pt},
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)}, xshift=12.5pt, anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)}, yshift=12.5pt, anchor=south west}
]


\addplot[samples=501, domain=-1000:37320.5] {-0.003*x^2 + 120*x - 500000};


%P = (25000, 625000) is a point on the parabola. The slope of the tangent line at P
%is -30. An equation for the tangent line at P is y = -30x + 1,375,000.
\coordinate (P) at (25000, 625000);
\coordinate (Q) at (137500/3, 0);

\end{axis}


%A "pin" is drawn to the parabola. 
\draw[draw=gray, shorten <=1mm, shorten >=1mm] (P) -- ($(P)!0.75cm!90:(Q)$);
\node[anchor=west, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($(P)!0.75cm!90:(Q)$){\makebox[0pt][l]{$y=P(x)$}};

\end{tikzpicture}




\end{document}
```

Comment: `scaled ticks=false`.

Comment: I see that `scaled ticks=false` prevented "10^{4}" from being printed.  Why was it printed?  I have not used that option in other `pgfplots`-graphs.

Comment: According to the manual **Allows to factor out common exponents in tick labels for linear axes. For example, if you have tick labels 20000, 40000 and 60000, you may want to save some space and write 2, 4, 6 with a separate factor ‘·10^4’. Use `scaled ticks=true` to enable this feature. In case of true, tick scaling will be triggered if the data range is either too large or too small (see below).**

Comment: Do you know why `xticklabels={$20,000$}` cannot be compiled?  Do you know how to get `20,000` typeset?

Comment: It compiles on my machine. Would you like to edit your post and show the non-working code?

Comment: I guess it does not compile because you have a comma inside the one number you want to have. Unfortunately the comma is used as a separator and thus LaTeX sees `$20` and `000$` which both have unbalanced `$`s. So the untested solution would be to provide extra braces like `xticklabels={{$20,000$}}`.

Comment: @Stefan Pinnow  Your suggestion did not work.  Use `xticklabels={\makebox[0pt]{$20,000$}}`.

Comment: Ok, but I don't see the point to write it that complicated. If you use `scaled ticks=false` and comment/delete the `xticklabels` line, it is already showing the number including the thousand separator ...

Comment: @AgalnamedDesire, could we help you to solve your problem or do you need further assistance?

Comment: @Stefan Pinnow  Your suggestion also typesets the label correctly.  Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it is solved in the comments.

Comment: @Stefan Pinnow  Yep.

Comment: @StefanPinnow why not answer the question instead of closing it?

Answer (score 2):

As Symbol 1 already stated in the comments below the question, the key is to set `scaled ticks=false` and the PGFPlots manual states to that key:

> Allows to factor out common exponents in tick labels for *linear axes*. For example, if you have tick labels 20000; 40000 and 60000, you may want to save some space and write 2; 4; 6 with a separate factor '$\cdot 10^4$'. Use `scaled ticks=true` to enable this feature. In case of `true`, tick scaling will be triggered if the data range is either too large or too small.

And since the number than already is showing up the way you want you don't need to state `xticklabels` any more.

(Please note that I did some other minor changes to the code as well which I don't have commented here.)

```
% used PGFPlots v1.14
\documentclass[border=15pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        width=3in,
        height=3in,
        axis lines=middle,
        xmin=-1000,
        xmax=37320.5,
        ymin=-200000,
        ymax=725000,
        xtick={20000},
        % ---------------------------------------------------------------------
        % you don't want the ticks/tick labels to be scaled
        scaled ticks=false,
%        % and the tick labels are shown by default the way you want them,
%        % so you don't need to specify them explicitely
%        xticklabels={$20000$},
        % ---------------------------------------------------------------------
        ytick={\empty},
        ticklabel style={font=\scriptsize},
        xlabel=$x$,
        ylabel=$y$,
        axis line style={
            latex-latex,
            shorten >=-12.5pt,
            shorten <=-12.5pt,
        },
        xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)}, xshift=12.5pt, anchor=north west},
        ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)}, yshift=12.5pt, anchor=south west},
    ]

        \addplot[samples=51,smooth,domain=-1000:37320.5] {-0.003*x^2 + 120*x - 500000};

        %P = (25000, 625000) is a point on the parabola. The slope of the tangent line at P
        %is -30. An equation for the tangent line at P is y = -30x + 1,375,000.
        \coordinate (P) at (25000, 625000);
        \coordinate (Q) at (137500/3, 0);

    \end{axis}

    %A "pin" is drawn to the parabola.
    \draw[draw=gray, shorten <=1mm, shorten >=1mm] (P) -- ($(P)!0.75cm!90:(Q)$);
    \node[anchor=west, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($(P)!0.75cm!90:(Q)$){$y=P(x)$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]